# what is and how to find the application manifest in flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I'm attempting to use google maps for flutter and I've run into a step I don't know how to do, any help is appreciated[the step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqs3O.png)

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the setup, the application manifest is in a subfolder within the android folder.

When you create a new Flutter project, flutter automatically creates both ios and android folders, so that you can put platform-specific items in the folders.

Look at the android folder, and follow the android/app/src/main path to find the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

**What is App Manifest?**

> Every app project must have an AndroidManifest.xml file (with
> precisely that name) at the root of the project source set. The
> manifest file describes essential information about your app to the
> Android build tools, the Android operating system, and Google Play.

This is also where you'll add your Google Maps API key so you can use Google Maps on your Android app built with Flutter.

You can find more info about it in the Android Developer's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro).

**How to find App Manifest in Flutter?**

You can find it in this path yourflutterproject/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml. See the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot].